# LOCK TABLE and try-catch block

Tags: java, mysql, locking, spring-jdbc

Inside a method annotated with `@Transactional`, should a `LOCK TABLE` statement be executed inside the `try` block or before it?

**Option 1:**

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_LOCK);

try {
    //Some work
} finally {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_UNLOCK);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
try {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_LOCK);

    //Some work
} finally {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_UNLOCK);
}
```

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: Lock inside try catch block would be recommended as it makes sure if any exception thrown on LOCKing tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 seems preferable since it guarantees executing of `SQL_UNLOCK` statement even if exception was thrown during executing of `SQL_LOCK`.

Comment: So, if an error occured during the first call to execute, it may be that the tables are locked?

Comment: May be. And may be not. But you cannnot be sure, so you have to unlock or at least try to unlock) the table. Otherwise it will remain locked forever.

Answer (score 1):

Choose **option 2**, it will do `finally` sql unlock whether exception is raised or not in `try-catch` block.

In case **option 1**, if the exception is raised before `try-catch` block in `SQL LOCK`, the program don't guarantee to enter `finally` block to unlock it back.